# magento 1.9 admin is disabled . How to enable backend again?

Tags: admin, backend

today is magento 1.9.3 admin showing a blank page. I suppose that it is because magento 1 is not supported anylonger. However for some personal reasons, I can't go to magento 2 ! How can I enable magento 1 admin ? Thanks

[image]

I uploaded saved site and database from 3 days ago as admin were working ok ... But admin is still not working !

Comment: Please check if there's any error logged on the log file. Or enable the error reporting and check if Magento throws any exceptions! It has nothing to do with support ended.

Comment: Thanks Bhaumik. I have 4 sites built with magento 1.9.3 and all have the same problem at the same time. This is why I thought it was because of the end of support. I have nothing in /var/report/ ... or maybe i should watch at another directory ? Thanks

Comment: @BhaumikUpadhyay please where can I see the log files ?

Comment: The log files are located in the <magento-folder>/var/log/ folder.

Comment: Also, have you checked by enabling the error reporting? For enabling error reporting, in Index page change the following: 1. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` 2. Set `$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true` 3. Uncomment this line
`#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` More, in Errors folder rename `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml`.

Comment: Just great ! Many thanks to you Bhaumik Upadhyay !!! I enabled error reporting in index.php. It showed an error concerning a carrier extension ( name CHRONOPOST )   and I was able to comment some code, and now it works well ! You saved my life :)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that there are no exceptions log. I can connect to admin url with login and password. But while logged, Linking to catalog, categories, orders etc ... nothing happens, admin page is still blank, whatever I click on ! all of my 4 magento 1.9.3 sites have the same trouble. Any idea ? If not because of the end of the support ... what else ? Many thanks

Comment: You can remove this one from the answer as it's not an answer but question/comment. Thanks.

Comment: sorry I don't find where to delete an answer ... ?

Comment: You will find the links right below your answer. For instance,  `share  edit  [delete]  flag`.

Comment: I only have share edit flag ( delete is missing ) !